# Formatar data para formato brasileiro usando webservices

Tags: java, android, datetime, formatação

Como formatar uma data timestamp para timestamp br.
ex.

```
2015-02-03 15:37:00 para 03/02/2015 15:37:00
```

obs: a data é um texto

Comment: Vem sempre neste padrao?

Comment: @DiegoF, Sim. Vem sempre nesse padrão

Comment: Formato string mesmo?

Comment: Sim. A data vem sempre de um webservice.

Comment: Digo, a saida(data formatada) que você espera tem que ser string correto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das formas pode ser conforme abaixo:

```
    String dataUS = "2015-02-03 15:37:00";

    SimpleDateFormat oldFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat newFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    System.out.println(newFormat.format(oldFormat.parse(dataUS)));
```

Que retorna:

> 03/02/2015 15:37:00

Veja em funcionamento no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/HKEaxV).